# Wifi connects but no internet (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, nmcli

I'm running Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and I'm trying to use internet through WiFi I already have a working internet connection with an ethernet cable on the same machine.

I'm running into a weird issue with my WiFi connection through the terminal I use the following command to connect to my WiFi network

```
sudo nmcli d wifi connect MYROUTERSSID password MYPASSWORD
```

I successfully connect to the wifi network

I then test to see if there is internet on the wireless interface by running the following command

```
ping -I wlx74da38839273 8.8.4.4
```

Now the problem

If I connect to my home wireless router I do get internet, but if I connect to any of my Android phones with tethering enabled, it does connect, but when I ping it I get 100% packet loss. I tried the Tethered connection on 3 different laptops running Windows and it works 100% fine. What are some the things to check for so I can troubleshoot this problem?